# How to match the TvLazyRow Title with the piviot offset of the items

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-tv, android-jetpack-compose-tv

Here is what i want my TvLazyColumnn to Look like:

[image: Tv Image]

I need to show the last passed item which is not a problem
but i also want to show the title of the TvLazyColumnn to match to the start or the highlighted item in TvLazyColumnn line PrimeVideo and many other apps does.

i have a workarount to give approximate padding and try but idk if it is the right solution and also then for different screen sizes it would not look good i feel.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using magic number padding is an okay solution because TVs don't have different screen sizes. All TVs have an aspect ratio of 16:9. If you use `dp` units in all your layout measurements, this will work on all TVs.

If you are not happy with using magic number paddings, you can look at the Pivot offset values and use that value to set the width of the `Spacer` composable before the title component.

```kotlin
val parentFraction = 0.3f

Column {
  Row(Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) {
    Spacer(Modifier.fillMaxWidth(parentFraction))
    Text("Title")
  }

  TvLazyRow(pivotOffsets = PivotOffsets(parentFraction)) {
      // items
  }
}
```